# angular-cli 'ng' commands sluggish

Tags: angular-cli

Versions:
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.18
node: 5.11.1
os: darwin x64 (macOS sierra)

> time ng -v results (note delay to execute 'ng-v'):
>   
>   `real    0m15.748s 
>   user    0m2.674s 
>   sys 0m0.461s`

Hi, I have installed the latest angular-cli using

> npm install -g angular-cli

on my iMac. All the ng commands lag by around 10 seconds before executing. Simplest example of slow execution is:

> ng -v

I have uninstalled angular-cli followed by

> npm cache clean

multiple times with no effect. BTW, I see this on beta.17 as well. As far as I see, other npm 'non-ng' packages execute without delay.  I only see it for 'ng'.

Does anyone have thoughts why mine lags and/or how I can narrow in the cause?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: same here on windows 10, it's boring.
I notice a rise in CPU usage 100% of one thread for 5 seconds.

Comment: `npm cache clean` doesn't remove global packages; it just cleans the cache. Run `npm install -g @angular/cli` to install the latest version of angular globally.